# Unexpected EventSource requests after updating Angular 4.4 to 5.2

Tags: websocket, webpack-dev-server, angular5, eventsource

I am trying to migrate web application I'm working on to Angular 5.2.

Followed the instructions on https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ ,
I've been able to run the application in the development mode using '**ng serve -lr'** as usually.
However, after application launches, multiple HTTP requests, which weren't triggering on Angular 4.4 are executing and eventually, webpack-dev-server disconnects.
My package.json on Angular 4.4, before update:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.0-RC.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.3.6",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "tinymce": "^4.6.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }, "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "htmlhint-ng2": "0.0.13",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.10.1",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "sass-lint": "latest",
    "scss-lint": "0.0.0",
    "scss-lint-html-reporter": "^0.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "sasslintConfig": "sass-lint.yml"
}
```

package.json after update to angular 5.2:

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.12",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^1.3.6",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.17.0",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "ng2-daterangepicker": "^2.0.12",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "tinymce": "^4.7.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.96",
    "codelyzer": "^4.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "htmlhint-ng2": "0.0.13",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.10.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "sass-lint": "latest",
    "scss-lint": "0.0.0",
    "scss-lint-html-reporter": "^0.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "sasslintConfig": "sass-lint.yml"
}
```

[Unexpected requests in the network tab of Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bahp7.jpg) 
[Browser console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxjlA.jpg) 
[Similar issue posted on angular-cli GitHub page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8590)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was in webpack live reloading. Solved it by adding parameter to launch script, now it is
`ng serve --public-host http://localhost:4200/ -lr`